# JAX-RS Restful POST without a fixed JSON body

Tags: java, json, rest, jax-rs

I have a rest service.

```
@POST
@Path("/feedback")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public void saveFeedback(FeedbackRequest feedback){
```

and my FeedbackRequest class has a JSONObject property.

```
public class FeedbackRequest {

private String message;
private JSONObject payload;
private String type;
```

The reason i put JSONObject in it is i can get any object with different attributes. But when i fire my api, I am getting bad request exception when processing 'payload'. 
My question is how can i process a dynamic json body data.

Comment: Why not just set the payload type to string? By this way you can process the payload json freely

Comment: If i put payload type as a string, then i have to again verify for json validity and i also have to store it in a database which has an ORM mapping. So if change the type i have to change entire mapping conf files. That is there, but i am in pursuit of an elegant way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My question is how can I process a dynamic JSON body data.

With Jackson, you could do the following:

```
public class FeedbackRequest {

    private String type;
    private String message;
    private Map<String, Object> payload;

    // Getters and setters
}
```

Alternatively you can use [`JsonNode`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JsonNode.html) instead of [`Map<K, V>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Map.html).

Comment: Is there any answer without changing the type of the payload object since it becomes difficult for me redo the whole orm mapping.

Comment: @Deadpool _Is there any answer without changing the type of the payload object [...]_ Your code is not even working with `JSONObject`...

Comment: And also the payload object can be complicated with JSONArrays and nested objects

Comment: @Deadpool I don't get what you are saying. Have you tested my solution?

Comment: Thank you so much. JsonNode worked perfectly fine.Thank you once again.